# Can't change grid-column through media query

Tags: css, css-grid

Can't figure out why my media query would not change the class .halfwidth to display the boxes LEFT RIGHT next to each other on desktop screens larger than 480px.

The media query itself works as can be seen by the background changing from green to white but grid-column is ignored.

```
.halfwidth {   
    grid-column: 1 / -1 ;    
    background: gray; 
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
   *{ background:green;}

    .halfwidth {
          grid-column: 1fr !important; 
        }
 }
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vaQNpm?editors=1100

Comment: simply because it's not a valid value ... you are probably looking for this `grid-column: auto;`

Comment: Yeah you are trying to use invalid value, read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column

Answer (score 0):

Like the problem you had in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51747396/3597276), your rules are invalid.

You're using the `fr` unit where [only grid lines are allowed](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#line-placement).

[image]

Just switch to [**`grid-column: auto`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-placement-auto) and you should be all set.

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JBwYVG?editors=1100)